# Is it possible to calculate the area of a golygon?

Tags: geometry, area

Silly question, how would one calculate the area of something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golygon And not just the simple example they have in the picture.

Is it any different from a normal polygon?

Comment: Divide it into disjoint rectangles, compute the area of the smaller rectangles, and add them up.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily use the $Pick's$ $theorem$, it is very useful for calculating the exact area of complicated shapes.$$A=i+\frac {b}{2}-1$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem

Comment: I like this method but perhaps for those who have not seen the theorem it might be nice to define the variables?

Answer (score 2):

You can just break it into things whose area you know, and then add everything up. Since the golygon only has right angles, I would suggest rectangles and squares.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!